# Configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables (OSX El Capitan)

Tags: c, macos, configure

I'm trying to install some software on my Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11) and when running its configure script, I'm getting a message that it cannot create executables.  I'm passing:

```
../configure \
--disable-diablo \
--download-essential  \
CC=/usr/local/bin/mpicc  \
CXX=/usr/local/bin/mpicxx  \
F77=/usr/local/bin/mpif77  \
FC=/usr/local/bin/mpif90  \
```

from a build directory.  I had to specify where the compilers are located as it would also return an error if I didn't.  Also, I am very new to this material so I would like to ask for a bit of patience if I take a while to understand whatever help is sent my way.

Also, I'm having trouble posting my config.log, so help with that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Can you create programs using those compilers?

Comment: actually, after some testing, it looks like my mpif77 is broken (trying 'mpif77 -help' , 'mpif77 - show' , nothing shows up).   I'm having trouble figuring out how to reinstall mpif77, would you know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry; can't help you any more than Google can. I'd have to hunt down where those compilers come from etc.  (I'd not heard of them before you asked this question.)  Try `mpif77 --version` (double dash, probably, though if that doesn't work, try a single dash, or just `-V`, or perhaps even `-v`).  That may tell you the version of the software.  It may not help you with compilation, per se.

Comment: The config.log is likely to be too big to be useful.  What might be relevant is the part where it diagnoses the compiler problem, which is likely to be near the end of the log.  If you can find 100 lines or less at the end which contain the error messages, they might tell you what's up, or you might be able to post those here.  Copy'n'paste into the edit window, then select them, then indent them by pressing the **`{}`** button above the edit window.   If you're feeling fancy, add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` as an unindented line on its own (blank line above and below) before the log file.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that the compiler failes a simple test of compiling a test code and running the resulting binary. You are trying to use `mpicc` to compile your project (is it necessary?) and it is only a wrapper for regular compiler, You have to have gcc or clang already in the system.

The easiest way to get all "Command line tools" including clang for macOS is to just install XCode and follow with `xcode-select --install` in terminal.